# Can’t connect to server (Socket)

Tags: java, android, client-server

```
public void connectAndRead(){

Socket socket = null;
try {
    socket = new Socket("192.168.1.11", 88);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(64);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

    int bytesRead;
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        String response1 = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        String[] delims = response1.split("[,]");
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        Double temp = Double.parseDouble(delims[0]);
        Double humidity = Double.parseDouble(delims[1]);
        String res = "Temp = " + temp + "Humidity = " + humidity;
        result.setText(res);
    }


} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have working server and resulting function `result.setText(res)`
But after `socket = new Socket("192.168.1.11", 88)` 
I have “finally” without any exceptions.
Where is mistake ?

Comment: did you added `INTERNET` permission ?

Comment: Yes, of course !

Comment: debug your code to find the problem